# Joomla 3.1 Override Libraries

Tags: php, html, joomla, overriding

I have a Joomla 3 website and want to override

`libraries/cms/html/html.php`.

Is it possible?

I tried to use same technique described here [How to override Joomla System Messages - message.php template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523287/how-to-override-joomla-system-messages-message-php-template)

I put my html.php file in `templates/MY_TEMPLATE/html/html.php`

this does not help, neither helps if I put in my template index.php file the following:

`require_once JPATH_ROOT .'/templates/'. $this->template .'/html/html.php';`

Comment: I would seriously be extremely careful with overriding a core file, especially one in the library.

Comment: Do you really want to override a library class, i.e. do you really want to affect the entire website or is it just for your specific content?

Comment: Yes, I do, this is for a site-wide change, and I want updates not to affect it in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can't override it using template overrides. It's an issue we have in Joomla which isn't solved yet.

The only way to override library files is if you provide a system plugin which will register an additional library path to the autoloader. Then it should be possible to override such classes. See http://developer.joomla.org/manual/ch01s04.html for information about the autoloader and how to register own libraries.