# How to add placeholders in joomla 2.5 without changing core library files

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have modified joomla core library files to facilitate to add placeholders for input fields. But it will be removed after do a version upgrade. Is there any solution for this?

I have checked this doc - http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core

And try to override by coping files to code folder in root. But it was not succeeded.

Root path - `code->libraries->joomla->form->fields->text.php`

Any solution will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [Template Overrides](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)

Comment: In the link you have provided, it has a section "Using a templating method" with the path that you have to use for your override.
TEMPLATE_NAME = /templates/your_template/

Comment: I have tried few times. I have moved them to template_name/my_template/libraries/joomla/form/fields/text.php
and also template_name/my_template/html/libraries/joomla/form/fields/text.php But it was not succeeded. Could you please correct me? Thanks

Comment: Can we override these library classes?

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have found a solution to override library files. I have used this Don  Gilbert's plugin and changed it to trigger onAfterInitialise event - https://gist.github.com/dongilbert/3237387

I was unable to install it directly. But I have changed this plugin as follows

Documentation to create own plugin - http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla

overrides.php

```
    defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;

/**
 * System plugin to override core classes terms.
 *
 * @package     Joomla.Plugin
 * @subpackage  System.Overrides
 * @since       2.5
 */
class PlgSystemOverrides extends JPlugin
{
    /* We do our thing in the __construct method
     * so that our overridden classes will be
     * available everywhere
     */
    public function __construct(&$subject, $config)
    {
        parent::__construct($subject, $config);

        //include_once 'config.php';
    }

    public function onAfterInitialise() {
        //include_once 'config.php';
        JLoader::register('JFormFieldText', JPATH_SITE.'/templates/speakeasy_comp/libraries/joomla/form/fields/text.php', true);
        }
}
```

Here I have overriding text.php by registering my edited file in template folder path for JFormFieldText class. J classes are stored in specific location. Please see this documentation - http://developer.joomla.org/manual/ch01s04.html

And also check this post - [Joomla 3.1 Override Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398302/joomla-3-1-override-libraries)

overrides.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="2.5" type="plugin" group="system" method="upgrade">
    <name>plg_system_overrides</name>
    <author>Don  Gilbert</author>
    <creationDate>Aug 2012</creationDate>
    <copyright>(C) 2012 Don Gilbert. All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license>
    <authorEmail>don@electriceasel.com</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>www.electriceasel.com</authorUrl>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
    <description>This plugin will override classes contained in the included config file.</description>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="overrides">overrides.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
    </files>
</extension>
```

I have changed Text.php file to facilitate placeholders as follows.

```
defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;

/**
 * Form Field class for the Joomla Platform.
 * Supports a one line text field.
 *
 * @package     Joomla.Platform
 * @subpackage  Form
 * @link        http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html#input.text
 * @since       11.1
 */
class JFormFieldText extends JFormField
{
    /**
     * The form field type.
     *
     * @var    string
     *
     * @since  11.1
     */
    protected $type = 'Text';

    /**
     * Method to get the field input markup.
     *
     * @return  string  The field input markup.
     *
     * @since   11.1
     */
    protected function getInput()
    {
        // Initialize some field attributes.
        $size = $this->element['size'] ? ' size="' . (int) $this->element['size'] . '"' : '';
        $maxLength = $this->element['maxlength'] ? ' maxlength="' . (int) $this->element['maxlength'] . '"' : '';
        $class = $this->element['class'] ? ' class="' . (string) $this->element['class'] . '"' : '';
        $readonly = ((string) $this->element['readonly'] == 'true') ? ' readonly="readonly"' : '';
        $disabled = ((string) $this->element['disabled'] == 'true') ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '';
                $placeholder = $this->element['placeholder'] ? ' placeholder="' . $this->element['placeholder'] . '"' : '';


        // Initialize JavaScript field attributes.
        $onchange = $this->element['onchange'] ? ' onchange="' . (string) $this->element['onchange'] . '"' : '';

        return '<input type="text" name="' . $this->name . '" id="' . $this->id . '"' . ' value="'
            . htmlspecialchars($this->value, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '"' . $class . $size . $disabled . $placeholder .$readonly . $onchange . $maxLength . '/>';
    }
}
```

I think this will be helpful for other also.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried this, however I don't see `placeholder` attribute added to my input elements in contact page form. Are there some other files, that need to be changed?

Comment: Did you add 'placeholder' in your form xml?

Comment: No I didn't, which `xml` file would be that? I mean which location is it in? Thanks.

Comment: That is form xml. When we are going to add a form we need to create form xml under model->forms folder in components. For example user profile plugin, there is form xml under plugins->user->profile->profiles->profile.xml. we need to define fields using field tags. Here you need to add 'placeholder' attribute. I think this may be help.

Comment: It is just like this.<field
    name="companyname"
    type="text"
    id="companyname"
    description="PLG_USER_PROFILE10_FIELD_COMPANY_DESC"
    filter="string"
    label="PLG_USER_PROFILE10_FIELD_COMPANY_LABEL"
    message="PLG_USER_PROFILE10_FIELD_COMPANY_MESSAGE"
    size="30"
                                placeholder="(if Applicable)"
   />

Comment: I am using Joomla's native `com_contact`, and I made plugin just like you said, so I don't have my own component for contact form. So where else should I make change, should I copy that `form.xml` from `com_contact/model/forms` to some location?

Comment: My goal is just to have instead of `label` in contact form, that same value as `html5` `placeholder` attribute. Nothing more, than that, so that what appeared as label now appears inside input field.

Comment: I added `placeholder` into `com_contact/models/forms/contact.xml` and now it appears in html source of that input field, but I don't know where and how to assign a value of label to it, would it be in `default_from` template override?

Comment: You should have to assign values like this. placeholder="Please enter name". This xml file is also need to override. because this default contact form of joomla. otherwise it will overwrite by new copy when you upgrade the system.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in **edit.php** for a particular field: (for multiple choice list box with use of bootstrap)

```
JHtml::_('formbehavior.chosen','#jform_fieldname', null, array('disable_search_threshold' => 0, 'placeholder_text_multiple' =>'placeholder Value'));
```

Answer (score -1):

This is very simple , you can add the placeholder by following steps:

1. Open `/components/com_users/models/forms/registration.xml`
2. Add `hint="place holder text here"`

Joomla is using `hint` attribute to place the placeholder.

Comment: This is a core change. Please don't use this!